# SQL query works in phpmyadmin but not when using jdbc and java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This query works when I input it through phpmyadmin.

```
INSERT INTO conversation (user_id) VALUES (?);
INSERT INTO conversation (conversation_id, user_id)
VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()), ?)
```

However when I send that query using jdbc and java I get an error -

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO conversation (conversation_id, user_id) VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_' at line 1"

I am using the exact same query. I checked by calling toString on the PreparedStatement and copying and pasting it into phpmyadmin and executing it and it worked fine. It just doesn't work through java. Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, you cannot execute multiple statements in one query through JDBC. Splitting it into two calls will work, as will changing the `allowMultiQueries` configuration property to `True`.

> [JDBC Configuration Properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) — `allowMultiQueries:`
>
> Allow the use of ';' to delimit multiple queries during one statement (true/false), defaults to 'false', and does not affect the addBatch() and executeBatch() methods, which instead rely on rewriteBatchStatements.
>
> Default value: `false`

Comment: Be aware that multiple queries are a non-standard extension of the MySQL Connector/J driver.